# error while go back to previous pages using breadcrumbs with reactjs and react-router-v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend, breadcrumbs

I'm make a breadcrumb using reactjs and react-router v5. I'm getting error when i'm click to previous page in breadcumbs. the application becomes hang. here's my breadcrumb.

[image]

showing the recent url pages is work. But the problem is when i want to back to previous page from breadcrumbs, my apps become hang, and i'm getting this error.

[image]

And then i'm getting the weird things about url. when i'm done in the last page. when i'm hover the link in breadcrumbs , it looks same.

[image]

it's weird , because the url of dashboard is '/'.

Here's my breadcrumbs code.

```
import React from "react";
import { Breadcrumb } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const Breadcrumbs = (props) => {
    const {
        history,
        location: {pathname}
    } = props;

    const pathnames = pathname.split("/").filter(x => x);

  return (
    <Breadcrumb aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <Link onClick={() => history.push("/")}> Dashboard</Link>

        {
            pathnames.map((name, index) => {
                const routeTo = `/${pathnames.slice(0, index + 1).join("/")}`;
                const isLast = index === pathnames.length - 1;
                return isLast ? (<>
                    <Breadcrumb.Item key={name}>{name}</Breadcrumb.Item> </>
                ) : (
                    <Link key={name}  onClick={() => history.push(routeTo)}>{name}</Link>
                )
            })
        }
    </Breadcrumb>
  );
};

export default  withRouter(Breadcrumbs);
```

I want my breadcrumbs work like this.
[Demo Breadcrumbs](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-ellis-4d0lc)

i'm stuck. any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `react-router-dom` `Link` component requires a `to` prop with a valid string or `Path` object with `pathname` property.

Instead of

```
<Link onClick={() => history.push("/")}>Dashboard</Link>
...
<Link key={name} onClick={() => history.push(routeTo)}>{name}</Link>
```

use

```
<Link to="/">Dashboard</Link>
...
<Link key={name} to={routeTo}>{name}</Link>
```